# How to make a fql multyquery with the PHP SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

I'm trying to make a fql multy query using the PHP SDK. This is my code

```
try {
    $fql = array( 
        "query1" => "SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()",
        "query2" => "SELECT name, url, pic FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM #query1)"
    );
    //$fql = "SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()";
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api( array(
        'method' => 'fql.multiquery',
        'query' => $fql,
    ) );
} catch ( FacebookApiException $e ) {
    error_log( print_r( $e->getMessage(), true ) );
    $user = NULL;
}
```

And this always returns an exception with no message

> [04-May-2012 20:22:26 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined property:
>   FacebookApiException::$getMessage in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\all-in-one-event-calendar\lib\plugins\A1ecFacebookConnectorPlugin.php
>   on line 120 [04-May-2012 20:22:26 UTC]

i'm obviously doing something wrong, what could that be?

Comment: It looks like the error is occurring within the exception handler and it's not showing the output of what threw the exception. Can you try `var_dump`ing `$e` in your exception handler to see what that spits out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok i found how to do this, you must use `queries` as a parameter, not `query`

```
try {
    $fql = array( 
        "query1" => "SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()",
        "query2" => "SELECT name, url, pic FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM #query1)"
    );
    //$fql = "SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()";
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api( array(
        'method' => 'fql.multiquery',
        'queries' => $fql,
    ) );
} catch ( FacebookApiException $e ) {
    error_log( print_r( $e->getMessage(), true ) );
    $user = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you are trying to call `$e->getMessage` which does not exist. Your code on line 120 should read:

```
error_log( print_r( $e, true ) );
```

If you have problems with the multiquery, you could do this as a single query:

```
$fql = "SELECT name, url, pic FROM profile WHERE id IN 
        (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() )";

$user_profile = $facebook->api( array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => $fql,
) );
```

I've been able to get a query running like this three SELECTs deep. Four SELECTs seems to be too much.

Comment: I was stupid, i just didn't save the file and i was accessing the property and not the method! :) Anyway i found a solution to do the multiquery, i'll post it, thanks for your help anyway